# Using Swift structure property in an objc file

Tags: ios, swift

I declare a `CLLocationCoordinate Property` in my swift class.Like

```
class SomeClass{
    var abc: CLLocationCoordinate?
    var aaa: CLLocation?
}
```

But,When I init this class in an objective-c file,It says there is no abc property.But my other property such as aaa exist.I guess its because that abc 
is a structure.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I highly recommend reading Apple's documentation.

Comment: I think this may be off-topic because this code is not the OP's actual code.

Answer (score 1):

> I declare a CLLocationCoordinate property

No, you don't. You declare a `CLLocationCoordinate?` property. That is a very different thing. An Optional wrapping a struct makes no sense to Objective-C.

Anyway, what *is* a CLLocationCoordinate in the first place? Core Location defines a CLLocationCoordinate2D type. But CLLocationCoordinate would have to be something you made up. So:

1. You should not be making up names that start with `CL`. That prefix belongs to Core Location, not to you.
2. If it's a struct, that's your problem. A Swift struct is not an object in Objective-C, so it cannot be understood by Objective-C, wrapped an Optional or not.
3. If you actually mean `CLLocationCoordinate2D?`, that still won't work, because a struct wrapped in an Optional makes no sense to Objective-C.

Comment: It's CLLocationCoordinate2D, I lost 2D.How to declare a CLLocationCoordinate2D property in swift class,delete the "?"?Thanks for your answer. : )

Comment: Sure, try that and see what happens. - And do not lie in Stack Overflow about your code. Always copy and paste it. You waste everybody's time when you show false code.

Comment: And how can Objective-C see this class at all if it doesn't derive from NSObject and is not declared `@objc`? Are you really showing anything at all like your real code????

Comment: My fault, my English is poor,I am not sensitive to English.Anyway ,thanks

Comment: uhh,My class is a subclass of NSObject,I try to make the code brief.

Comment: This is not a matter of English. We all speak Swift. You must show your _real_ Swift code. Do not lie to Stack Overflow about your code!